# I deleted the object file of a c++ program still the .exe file is executing how this is possible?

Tags: c++, object

I'm using code blocks IDE and GNU GCC compiler. when i create a simple program like e.g. add.cpp (for adding two number) it usually creates two file add.exe (executing file) add.o(object file) according to some of them add.o is linked to add.exe while executing.
my question is i deleted the add.o still the add.exe is executing and still producing the required results. how this is possible if the object file is  missing ?? and please also explain me what object file really does ??

Answer (score 2):

The object file is linked at compilation time... The object file is then redundant post all the compilation. The o files are maintained between builds so you don't need to rebuild unchanged parts of your application.

Answer (score 2):

From source to executable (in a really oversimplified sort of way):

1) The pre-processor gathers the #include'd files for each .cpp in turn, runs macros, etc, and produces a "translation unit" for each file. These contain all the includes, and the macros have been evaluated: it's otherwise recognisable as source code.

2) The compiler runs over each translation unit, and turns the source into machine-instructions in "object files". These object files contain references (called "symbols") to the functions and variables it has defined, and those that are mentioned but never defined.

3) The linker grabs all the object files, and matches up the symbols across different object files. It then produces an executable.

You can freely run your executable without either the source or object files: these were read in order to produce the next step. Object files are left behind because usually you don't need to rebuild everything each time you press compile: if you only changed one source file, you only need build one new object file, and one new executable.

Comment: Worth mentioning, and other people's answers touch upon these, is that there are a number of conditions and caveats with this (namely using external libraries). As a basic model of "How did I go from 'int main()' to 'double click .exe to run'", it should suffice as a starting model.

Answer (score 1):

Files `.o` are not linked to `exe` at runtime, they are linked to it at compile time (specifically, during the linking step). Once you have an executable, you can safely remove all object files that were linked into it. It is also OK to remove all static libraries that were statically linked into the `exe`, because their content becomes part of the executable.

Answer (score 1):

the object file contain the result of the compilation. the exe file contain the result of the link. You can delete the o file if you want exe still working

Answer (score 0):

The `.o` file is used for compiling, the `.exe`. Where the `.o` is an **compiled object code** to be later used to compile other programs.

Where as the `.exe` is the compiled file, and does not require `.o`.

Given compiling:

```
g++ -c Hello.cpp -o Hello.o
g++ Hello.o main.cpp -o mainprogram.exe
```

The first line, creates a `.o` file but does not do external linking. The second line uses this `.o` and `.cpp` file and links your program together.

The only files you require for a program to function that are not in `.exe` are `.so` files or `.a` which are shared and static libraries respectively.

For object file this may help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of linking: static and dynamic. When you compile something the compiler produces object files which are linked statically into your executable. Only if you use an external library and only if you link dynamically against it will you need to have access to it.

Comment: This isn't related to an .o file.